# Ordering: Compactness

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Denote selfadjoints:
$$\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}):=\{A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):A=A^*\}$$

Introduce an order:
$$A\leq A':\iff\sigma(A'-A)\geq0$$

Denote compacts:
$$\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H}):=\{K\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):K\text{ compact}\}$$

Regard operators:
$$A,B\in\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}):\quad0\leq A\leq B$$

Then one has:
$$R\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad BR\in\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})\implies AR\in\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})$$

How can I check this?

Comment: Is this question to easy? *(Downvote?!)*

Comment: What's $K$? ${}{}$

Comment: @JohnMa: Oh, I'm sorry: Let $\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})$ be compact operators. *(I added it above.)*

Comment: What do you mean by $0\leqslant A\leqslant A'$? That $A, A'$ are positive operators (i.e. self-adjoint and $f\ne 0$ implies $\langle Af, f\rangle >0$) and $\|A\| \leqslant \|A'\|$?

Comment: @Math1000: I usually prefer the spectral values definition but as this question is operator-theoretic you are welcome to work with the numerical range instead. ;)

Comment: So by $\sigma(A'-A)\geqslant0$ you mean that the spectrum of $A'-A$ is a subset of the nonnegative real numbers? I am confused because I took a course in operator theory and have not seen this notation...

Comment: @Math1000: Operator-theoretic or operator-algebraic course? The former rather work with spectrum while the latter rather with the numerical range.

Comment: @Freeze_S I'm not sure what you mean exactly; we studied bounded and unbounded linear operators as well as operator algebras. But it was an introductory course. I'm just pointing out that if your notation isn't clear to someone with some background in the subject, it probably isn't clear to others as well ;)

Comment: @Math1000: Ah right good point!! *(Let me add more details.)*

Comment: @Math1000: Study of operator algebras usually involves operator-algebraic techniques such as approximate identities while study of unbounded operators rather works with operator-theoretic concepts such as sesquilinear forms, but both not exclusively.

Comment: @Math1000: Is that readable what I wrote? *(You can be honest.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I finally got it.. :D*

By another thread:
$$\|K\varphi\|=\langle K^*K\varphi,\varphi\rangle\leq\|K^*K\varphi\|\cdot\|\varphi\|$$

So equivalence holds:
$$K\in\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})\iff K^*K\in\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})$$

Thus one has the chain:
$$BR\in\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})\implies R^*\sqrt{B}\sqrt{B}R=R^*BR\in\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})\implies\sqrt{B}R\in\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})$$

Conjugation gives:
$$A\leq B\implies R^*AR\leq R^*BR$$

But for selfadjoints:
$$S\in\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}):\quad\langle\sigma(S)\rangle=\overline{\mathcal{W}(S)}$$

So one estimates:
$$\|\sqrt{A}R\varphi\|^2=\langle R^*AR\varphi,\varphi\rangle\leq\langle R^*BR\varphi,\varphi\rangle=\|\sqrt{B}R\varphi\|^2$$

Thus the chain proceeds:
$$\sqrt{B}R\in\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})\implies\sqrt{A}R\in\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})\implies AR\in\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})$$

Concluding the assertion.